# resources vs resource with root path set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

if I have

```
resources :projects 
root to: "projects#index"
```

in my routes file would it be more succinct to do

```
resource :projects
root to: "projects#index"
```

or any reason this won't work because I don't see anyone doing it

Comment: Why would you do that? Wouldn't you have more than one project?

Comment: good point, thanks, noob...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because they’re two different methods that do two different things. [`resources`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) is meant for when you have more than one of the model object (a *plural* resource), whereas [`resource`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource) is meant for when it is a *singular* resource. For this reason, using `resource` does not create an `index` route and none of the routes take an ID parameter in the URL. To quote [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource):

> Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID. A common example, /profile always shows the profile of the currently logged in user. In this case, you can use a singular resource to map /profile (rather than /profile/:id) to the show action:
>
> ```
> resource :geocoder
> ```

That said, I wouldn't really consider saving one character “more succinct” anyway.